# I need to display alt characters

Tags: css, fonts, squarespace

I need some help with accessing alt characters ie. a, n, m, r from a web font that I installed in square-space. I'm using css and the font is working however I don't know how to get the alt options for those letters.

Might be tricky but I don't want the whole site to change to the alt characters, I want to select which text shows them. ie, header or title or part of paragraph. The file is a web font.

Thanks so much!
K